Adding 2D numpy arrays with differing axes arrays: how to properly replace the deprecated interp2d with RectBivariateSpline?
I need to add two 2D numpy arrays of possibly different shapes and different corresponding axes arrays.
What I mean is this: Lets define two different sets of x- and y-axes, and calculate the z-values according to some function (here: a 2D Gaussian distribution):
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def gaussian_2D(X, Y, amplitude, mu_x, mu_y, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta, offset=0):
    """
    X,Y: are expected to be numpy meshgrids
    """
    a = (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    b = -(np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_y**2)
    c = (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    return offset + amplitude*np.exp( - (a*((X-mu_x)**2) + 2*b*(X-mu_x)*(Y-mu_y) + c*((Y-mu_y)**2)))


x1 = np.linspace(10, 100, num=100)
y1 = np.linspace(0, 200, num=100)
X1,Y1 = np.meshgrid(x1,y1)
Z1 = gaussian_2D(X1,Y1, 10, 35, 100, 10, 20, 0)

x2 = np.linspace(0, 150, num=120)
y2 = np.linspace(30, 220, num=120)
X2,Y2 = np.meshgrid(x2,y2)
Z2 = gaussian_2D(X2,Y2, 10, 75, 150, 5, 4, 12)

The above code generates 2 differing x-arrays of lengths (100,) and (120,), 2 differing y-arrays of lengths (100,) and (120,) and 2 z-arrays of shape (100,100) and (120,120).
The x- and y-arrays define some physical dimension, here space in units of millimeter, so that it makes sense to add the two together, even though the underlying arrays are different. I have chosen these axes to be overlapping, but really there is no need for that, the arrays could be completely seperate. Plotting them shows what is going on:
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pcolormesh(X1,Y1,Z1)
ax1.set_xlim([0,150])
ax1.set_ylim([0,220])
ax1.set_xlabel("x [mm]")
ax1.set_ylabel("y [mm]")

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.pcolormesh(X2,Y2,Z2)
ax2.set_xlim([0,150])
ax2.set_ylim([0,220])
ax2.set_xlabel("x [mm]")
ax2.set_ylabel("y [mm]")

results in:


And we can get a sense of what the resulting plot should look like when the two arrays are added by simply plotting them on top of each other with some alpha value:
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
ax3.pcolormesh(X1, Y1, Z1, alpha=0.5)
ax3.pcolormesh(X2, Y2, Z2, alpha=0.3)
ax3.set_xlabel("x [mm]")
ax3.set_ylabel("y [mm]")



Now, clearly because the underlying structure of the arrays is different, we must use some interpolation to "standardize" the two arrays onto some common grid. For the sake of convenience, lets make the resulting array always (100, 100) (i.e. roughly the same shape as the two input arrays. This is an assumption that will usually hold for me..... let's ignore edge cases...)
def add_arrays_with_axes(array_1, array_1_x, array_1_y, array_2, array_2_x, array_2_y, method="interp2d"):
    import scipy.interpolate as interp

    # Define the new x and y axis ranges that cover both array_1 and array_2 axes
    new_x = np.linspace(min(array_1_x[0], array_2_x[0]), max(array_1_x[-1], array_2_x[-1]), num=100)
    new_y = np.linspace(min(array_1_y[0], array_2_y[0]), max(array_1_y[-1], array_2_y[-1]), num=100)
    
    # Interpolate array_1 and array_2 onto the new grid
    match method:
        case "interp2d":
            interp_array_1 = interp.interp2d(array_1_x, array_1_y, array_1, kind='cubic', bounds_error=False, fill_value=np.nan)
            interp_array_2 = interp.interp2d(array_2_x, array_2_y, array_2, kind='cubic', bounds_error=False, fill_value=np.nan)

        case "RectBivariateSpline":
            interp_array_1 = interp.RectBivariateSpline(array_1_x, array_1_y, array_1)
            interp_array_2 = interp.RectBivariateSpline(array_2_x, array_2_y, array_2)

        case _:
            raise Exception("Unsupported interp method.")
    
    # Evaluate the interpolations on the new x and y grid
    array_1_resampled = interp_array_1(new_x, new_y)
    array_2_resampled = interp_array_2(new_x, new_y)
    
    # Replace NaNs with 0 in each array where data was not originally defined
    array_1_resampled = np.nan_to_num(array_1_resampled, nan=0.0)
    array_2_resampled = np.nan_to_num(array_2_resampled, nan=0.0)
    
    # Sum the resampled arrays
    summed_array = array_1_resampled + array_2_resampled
    
    return summed_array, new_x, new_y

In the above I allow for the use of two different interpolation methods: interp2d and RectBivariateSpline.
Let's see what the result is:
interp2d
new_array, new_x, new_y = add_arrays_with_axes(Z1, x1, y1, Z2, x2, y2, method="interp2d")
new_mesh = np.meshgrid(new_x, new_y)

fig4, ax4 = plt.subplots()
ax4.pcolormesh(X1, Y1, Z1, alpha=0.5)
ax4.pcolormesh(X2, Y2, Z2, alpha=0.3)
ax4.set_xlabel("x [mm]")
ax4.set_ylabel("y [mm]")

ax4.pcolormesh(*new_mesh, new_array)



RectBivariateSpline
new_array, new_x, new_y = add_arrays_with_axes(Z1, x1, y1, Z2, x2, y2, method="RectBivariateSpline")
new_mesh = np.meshgrid(new_x, new_y)

fig5, ax5 = plt.subplots()
ax5.pcolormesh(X1, Y1, Z1, alpha=0.5)
ax5.pcolormesh(X2, Y2, Z2, alpha=0.3)
ax5.set_xlabel("x [mm]")
ax5.set_ylabel("y [mm]")

ax5.pcolormesh(*new_mesh, new_array)


Clearly the two methods show very different results
interp2d shows very much what I expected to happen: you only get values where the original arrays were defined, and zeros where they were undefined, leading to the visible edge at x=10.
RectBivariateSpline, on the other hand, seems to not only stretch the data, but also move the data.... Compare for example the central point of the broader Gaussian. It was defined to be at (x=35, y=100), and interp2d reproduces this correctly, but in the RectBivariateSpline case the center moved somewhere more like (x=35, y=80). Why does it do that? It seems like interp2d is the way to go, but that function is actually discontinued. RectBivariateSpline does have one more possibly relevant argument: bbox, but I am unsure what it does, and also what I would set it to other than the original bounding box the original array, which it defaults to anyway... Plus there seems to be some issue with this argument anyway.
Any ideas what is happening with RectBivariateSpline?

I think this question is essentially how to properly replace deprecated interp2d with RectBivariateSpline, I suggest you edit your title to reflect that.

(been looking at the docs and playing with your toy example, and I'm quite confused too...)

Looking at the __call__ method of RectBivariateSpline we see that the code expects the points in indexing="ij" format, while np.meshgrid defaults to indexing="xy" (don't ask me why). To fix this you will need to make two changes:

Transpose the data arrays when creating the RectBivariateSpline objects.

case "RectBivariateSpline":
    interp_array_1 = interp.RectBivariateSpline(array_1_x, array_1_y, array_1.T)
    interp_array_2 = interp.RectBivariateSpline(array_2_x, array_2_y, array_2.T)


Create new_mesh using the "ij" ordering.

new_mesh = np.meshgrid(new_x, new_y, indexing="ij")

This will produce matching results with interp2d.
You should also keep in mind that RectBivariateSpline extrapolates while interp2d fills unknown values (in your case you're filling with np.nan). This will only be an issue if you have some structure near/at the boundary of one dataset and that boundary is shared between the two datasets.

Alternatively, for a complete transition, you just need to switch the indexing to "ij" for all the np.meshgrid calls. The rest of the code can remain as is (interp2d will no longer be correct, but that function is deprecated so it shouldn't matter).

Correct me if I am wrong, but this seems like a trip hazard..... So not only do I need to supply RectBivariateSpline with a transposed array (the reason for this being not at all obvious from the docs....), but then I also need to remember that if I ever want to plot the interpolated array, I need to use a meshgrid generated with non-default indexing?

If you're looking to completely switch over to RectBivariateSpline, you can use your original code but change all the np.meshgrids to use indexing="ij". Then you won't have to do any transposes.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate/interp_transition_guide.html details how to replicate interp2d, in both scattered and grid modes
